Proof of associativity of union
This may be a rather simple question, but how do I prove associativity? I ask because, as I'm following Tao's analysis, the proof provided by him seems unnecessarily long. Before I give my proof, here's the axiom that is used:
"For two sets $A$ and $B$, there exists a set $A\cup B$ such that $x\in A\cup B\iff x\in A\lor x\in B$."
Now, here's my suggested proof:
For $(A\cup B)\cup C$, the following must hold by definition of the union:
$$x\in (A\cup B)\cup C\iff x\in A\cup B\lor x\in C$$
This further simplifies to:
$$x\in (A\cup B)\cup C\iff x\in A\lor x\in B\lor x\in C$$
Now, if you consider $A\cup (B\cup C)$, you get the following:
$$x\in A\cup (B\cup C)\iff x\in A\lor x\in B\cup C$$
$$x\in A\cup (B\cup C)\iff x\in A\lor x\in B\lor x\in C$$
From here, we can see that $\forall x\in (A\cup B)\cup C, x\in A\cup (B\cup C)$ and vice versa. Thus, associativity is proved. So is this approach correct? Or does it assume something additional?

When you write $x\in A\vee x\in B\vee x\in C$, you are implicitly assuming the associativity of the logical operator $\vee$. Hence I would propose a slightly different approach:
\begin{align*}
x\in A\cup(B\cup C) & \Longleftrightarrow (x\in A)\vee(x\in B\cup C) \tag{Def. of Union}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x\in A)\vee((x\in B)\vee(x\in C)) \tag{Def. of Union}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow ((x\in A)\vee(x\in B))\vee(x\in C) \tag{Associativity of $\vee$}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow (x\in A\cup B)\vee(x\in C) \tag{Def. of Union}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x\in(A\cup B)\cup C \tag{Def. of Union}
\end{align*}
Hopefully this helps!
